# QUERY_STRING string not working nginx ubuntu 12.04 EC2 server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, query-string, php

I have migrated from apache2 to nginx on my ubuntu 12.04 EC2 server, But its not working I never receive query_string.
I'm running nginx with php5-fpm

nginx version: nginx/1.4.5

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/example;
    index index.html index.php;
    server_name www.example.com;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.example.com error;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.exmaple.com;

    location / {
            # Check if a file or directory index file exists, else route it to index.php.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

     # PHP FPM configuration.
    location ~* \.php$ {
            #fastcgi_pass                    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_pass                    127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index                   index.php;
            fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
            include                         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    # Set header expirations on per-project basis
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|jpe?g|JPG|png|svg|woff)$ {
            expires 365d;

    }

    charset UTF-8;
    }
```

My fastcgi_params file looks like this,

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;

fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI     $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI        $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT       $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL     $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE     nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR     $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT     $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR     $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT     $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME     $server_name;

fastcgi_param   HTTPS           $https if_not_empty;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS     200;
```

Answer (score 0):

It works great for me using your same configuration.  Did you try creating a php script with a call to `php_info()` ?

[image: Query String]

Are you pointing to the the right root `/var/www/example;` ?